# Instant Messaging in SharePoint Online

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, skype-for-business

I got a requirement of implementing Instant Messenger in SharePoint.
As we are using Office 365 which is having apps like Outlook Web with Skype for business integrated like [image], is there any option of implementing Skype for business with SharePoint online ?
If not, please suggest some Instant Messengers that can be used.